what is the syntax for 'if let' with struct-like enum value
I have an enum
enum Event {
    Key {
        key: u8,
        physical_key: Option<u8>,
        pressed: bool,
    },
    Foo,
}

What syntax do I use for
fn main() {
    let event = Event::Key {
        key: 42,
        physical_key: None,
        pressed: true,
    };
    if let Event::Key(?????) = event
    {}
}

Ie Test if the event is an Event::Key and if so get its data

enum Event {
    Key {
        key: u8,
        physical_key: Option<u8>,
        pressed: bool,
    },
    Foo,
}

fn main() {
    let event = Event::Key {
        key: 42,
        physical_key: None,
        pressed: true,
    };
    // full
    if let Event::Key {
        key,
        physical_key,
        pressed,
    } = event
    {}
    // ignore value
    if let Event::Key { .. } = event {}
    // partial
    if let Event::Key { key, .. } = event {}
    // bind field
    if let Event::Key {
        key: amazing_key, ..
    } = event
    {}
}


ty, not obvious to me, and none of the rust references/ guides etc show it. The other weird one is if you are not interested in a field you have to go pressed:_ - again not obvious

@pm100 the answer shows you can do .. to ignore the other fields so you don't have to field: _

@pm100 Not sure what references/guides you've been using, but this is covered in the Rust book.

@cdhowie it's not in the 'if let' docs anywhere. You had to know that this is called destructuring and that that's what you need here

@pm100 From here: "The syntax if let takes a pattern and an expression separated by an equal sign. It works the same way as a match, where the expression is given to the match and the pattern is its first arm." This pretty much explicitly says that anything you can do with a single match arm you can do with if let. It's the same syntax ("pattern matching").
